# Capitalize select option using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu.

[image]

I've been trying to capitalize the text inside my select option, but I couldn't make it work.

---

**JS**

```
$.each(responseData.assignments, function(i, v) {
  var chapterNum = v.contentLabel;
  var assessmentType = v.assessmentType.toLowerCase().replace(/_/g, " ");

  var sameAssignmentType = $('#assignment-type-dd option').filter(function(){
      return $(this).text() == assessmentType;
  })

  if(!sameAssignmentType.length){
    $('#assignment-type-dd').append('<option value="' + assessmentType + '">' +
        assessmentType + '</option>');
  }

});
```

I've tried chaining this code to my `assessmentType` :

`.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)`

But as soon as I do that it give error :

`Uncaught TypeError: this.slice is not a function`

Can someone please give me a little hint here ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe using [code]this[/code] at a Jquery object won't work.

Comment: Are you trying to capitalize every first letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work (CSS approach)

```
#assignment-type-dd option {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

If you need the entire options text to be uppercase use this.

```
#assignment-type-dd option {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And if you really hate CSS or you need the Capitalized text to be passed to server or do some other manipulation, use the below JavaScript code

```
var capitalizeMe = "";
$("#assignment-type-dd option").each(function() {

  capitalizeMe = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(capitalizeMe.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + capitalizeMe.substring(1));
});
```

Play it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfzhc4gs/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `this.slice(1)`, try using `assessmentType.slice(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to format it as

```
 string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use a CSS rule:

```
select option {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can manipulate font setting by CSS alternation also. Try this

```
<style>
 select option {
   text-transform:capitalize;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem CSS is best-suited for.

```
.select {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, unless you are trying to capitalize the first letter of each word. In which case a pure JavaScript solution (assuming you are targeting `h2` elements) would be:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var words = a[i].innerHTML.split(" ");
    for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (words[j][0] != "&") {
            words[j] = "<span class='first-letter'>" + words[j][0] + "</span>" + words[j].substring(1);
        }
    }
    a[i].innerHTML = words.join(" ");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/2uLLqy8r/

Otherwise pure css will work: `text-transform: capitalize;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Answer (score 1):

If it is about just showing it then the css text-transform should work.

If you want to do it programatically in Javascript, I suggest creating a function and calling it as needed:

```
 function stringCapitalize(str){
   if (str){
      str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
      return str;
   }
}

stringCapitalize("moemen"); // returns "Moemen"
```

If you think that you will use it regularly during this application, then add it to the built-in String.prototype:

```
String.prototype.stringCapitalize = function () { 
    if (this){
      str = this;
      str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
      return str;
   }
}

"moemen".stringCapitalize() // returns "Moemen"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = prompt("what is your name"); 
var firstchar = name.slice(0, 1); 
var firstcharuppercase = firstchar.toUpperCase(); 
var restofName = name.slice(1,name.length); 
var capitlisedName = firstcharuppercase + restofName; 
alert(" Hello " + capitlisedName);
```