# Upper case all Select option values on the drop down list on Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I want to capitalise all the text that is shown when you click on the select, this is my current code

```css
.select__input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<select class="select__input">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="val1">Value</option>
  <option value="val2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

This work on Chrome, but on fireFox it still seems to be lowercase, is there any way i can change the select text for all browsers

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Comment: This seems to be a bug that is still open: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1445885. You will probably have to modify the text using javascript

Comment: It's funny that browsers which use older versions of Gecko, such as SeaMonkey and PaleMoon, still display the texts in uppercase. So this is something that only stopped working recently.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows that there is already an [open bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1445885) for this issue in which another [closed bug is linked](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1445885) that seems to suggest that they're still in the process of supporting other style properties for child `option` elements.

You will have to; for the time being, manually adjust the capitalisation with Javascript. There's already a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124597/capitalize-select-option-using-javascript) about how to do just that.

Hope that helps